# Meaning of "How much you had? Woah, must be gone. You must have since lunchtime"

Tags: meaning, british-english

The text is from Over There by Mark Ravenhill. What is this part referring to: "How much you had? Woah, must be gone. You must have since lunchtime."

> Franz: Brilliant that’s brilliant. It’s a mirror. Ha ha.
> That is fucking great. I love that. I fucking love that,
> it’s a mirror.
>
> Karl: You want a beer, a steak and a shag. And so do I
> a beer, a steak and a shag. So let’s
>
> Franz: Keep
>
> Karl: The
>
> Franz: Suits
>
> Karl: On
>
> Franz: And
>
> Karl: Get
>
> Franz: A
>
> Karl: Beer
>
> Franz: A
>
> Karl: Steak
>
> Franz: And
>
> Karl: A
>
> Franz: Shag.
>
> Karl / Franz: How much you had? Woah, must be
> gone. You must have since lunchtime. Two? I don’t
> think. Two? In your dreams. In your fucking. What so
> there’s another? I don’t see. There’s only me. There’s
> only special unique wonderful you better believe it.
> . . .
> Reckon you could take it twice? Hungry enough? Big
> enough? You wide? You wet? Double the? In your
> fucking.
> . . .
> Open wide the twins are coming inside.

Comment: Probably referring to drinking habits.

Comment: Said fast, dropping the have: How much [have] you had? Often dropped in colloquial speech. However, the paragraph has bits that just sound like a drunk.